# Spring custom auth filter and custom jwtfilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

What I'm trying to implement is to make my multitenant app workspace aware. With this I mean that besides username and password, I'm validating the workspace as well.

Before, I had (working) normal authentication (username and password) and a JWTFilter that is a OncePerRequestFilter.

**What I did?**

- Extended **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken**: just to add the workspace
- Extended **AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider**: defining my customPasswordEncoder and customUserDetailsService
- Made a **CustomUserDetailsService**: instead of the loadByUsername I've made a loadUserByWorkspaceAndUsername
- Configured the **WebSecurity** for the new extended classes

The outcome is always unauthorized :(

**What I've tried?**
While debugging the code never pass on the CustomAuthenticationFilter and that's the reason I'm focusing my efforts there. Really doesn't know what I'm doing wrong here. If you need any further information please shout.

Replacing the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter using the `addFilter(authenticationFilter())`

```
 .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(authenticationFilter(), JwtFilter.class);
```

```
 .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
              .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

```
 .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

A bit of code.

**CustomAuthenticationToken**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {

    private String workspace;

    public CustomAuthenticationToken(final Object principal,
                                     final Object credentials,
                                     final String workspace) {
        super(principal, credentials);
        this.workspace = workspace;
    }

    public CustomAuthenticationToken(final Object principal,
                                     final Object credentials,
                                     final String workspace, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(principal, credentials, authorities);
        this.workspace = workspace;
        super.setAuthenticated(true);
    }

    public String getWorkspace() {
        return this.workspace;
    }
}
```

**CustomAuthenticationFilter**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_DOMAIN_KEY = "workspace";

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: "
                    + request.getMethod());
        }

        CustomAuthenticationToken authRequest = getAuthRequest(request);
        setDetails(request, authRequest);
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    private CustomAuthenticationToken getAuthRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);
        String domain = obtainDomain(request);

        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }
        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }
        if (domain == null) {
            domain = "";
        }

        username = username.trim();
        return new CustomAuthenticationToken(username, password, domain);
    }

    private String obtainDomain(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter(SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_DOMAIN_KEY);
    }
}
```

**CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider**

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    /**
     * The plaintext password used to perform
     * PasswordEncoder#matches(CharSequence, String)}  on when the user is
     * not found to avoid SEC-2056.
     */
    private static final String USER_NOT_FOUND_PASSWORD = "userNotFoundPassword";
    private final PasswordEncoder customPasswordEncoder;
    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    private String userNotFoundEncodedPassword;

    public CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider(final PasswordEncoder customPasswordEncoder,
                                                   final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        this.customPasswordEncoder = customPasswordEncoder;
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(final UserDetails userDetails,
                                                  final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }

        final String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        if (!customPasswordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(final String username,
                                       final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final CustomAuthenticationToken auth = (CustomAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        UserDetails loadedUser;

        try {
            loadedUser = this.customUserDetailsService.loadUserByWorkspaceAndUsername(auth.getWorkspace(), auth.getPrincipal().toString());
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException notFound) {
            if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
                String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
                customPasswordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userNotFoundEncodedPassword);
            }

            throw notFound;
        } catch (Exception repositoryProblem) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(repositoryProblem.getMessage(), repositoryProblem);
        }

        if (loadedUser == null) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation");
        }

        return loadedUser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAfterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(this.customUserDetailsService, "A UserDetailsService must be set");
        this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword = this.customPasswordEncoder.encode(USER_NOT_FOUND_PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

**CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements CustomUserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(com.cliwise.security.workspace.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

    private final LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    public CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl(LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService, UserRepository userRepository, HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.loginAttemptService = loginAttemptService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByWorkspaceAndUsername(String workspace, String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final User user = userRepository.findByUsernameOrEmailAndWorkspace(username, username, workspace)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User not found with username or email : " + username));

        return UserPrincipal.create(user);
    }
}
```

The last but no least
**WebSecurity**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
    private final CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider customUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider;

    public WebSecurity(final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler,
                       final CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider customUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
        this.customUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider = customUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter filter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), CustomAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtFilter();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Where do you use `authenticationFilter` in your WebSecurity configuration ?

Comment: Hi @chaoluo, I've tried yes. The code I've posted if you notice I'm declareing the CustomAuthenticationFilter.class and I've also added above the attempts I've made.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are facing the problem in CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider. Since you are extending AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProver you will get a default implementation for

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException;
```

See if its properly authenticating the authentication object, if not you will have to override the method and write your own implementation.

Comment: What about the filters? Does the order matters? First the auth and than the jwt seems alright?

Comment: Order usually don't affect the authentication, an AuthenticationProvider can return null from the authenticate(Authentication) method to indicate another AuthenticationProvider should be tried.
 Also UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter will only work for "/login" urls, unlike Once per request filters which would intercept all the requests.